# package javapns.back and javapns.data does not exist

Tags: java, maven, apple-push-notifications

I try to added maven dependency into my project but i got the error like this and for that also got the error like **symbol cannot found**.

> [ERROR] /C:/abc/src/com/util/ApplePushManager.java:[11,20] package
>   javapns.back does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/abc/src/com/ibn/util/ApplePushManager.java:[12,20] package
>   javapns.data does not exist
>
> /C:/abc/src/com/ibn/util/ApplePushManager.java:[57,93] cannot find
>   symbol   symbol:   variable SSLConnectionHelper
>
> /C:/Users/abc/src/com/ibn/util/ApplePushManager.java:[27,43] cannot
>   find symbol   symbol:   variable PushNotificationManager

I added **javapns-jdk16 and javapns_2.2** dependency for push notification but still i got the error. Does anybody know what I have done wrong?

if anyone knows the answer please help me.
its very appreciated.